# How to display the code of a java class in a web page (jsp)

Tags: java, jsp

I'm developing a web page containing a list of existing java class name :

so when the user click the link of the java class name a new web page is opened containing the code of this java class .
so to do it i will use a flow to read the file (java class) and write it on a web page .
Have you another optimized solution ?

Comment: You should have the source file for this, not just the class file.

Answer (score 4):

Use `<c:import />` JSTL and embed the content in `<pre></pre>` tag.

```
<c:import var="content" url="File.java"/>
<pre>
 <c:out value="${content}"/>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just read the .java file like any other text file.  Note make sure you are doing it with the .java files and not compiled .class files.

You can then optionally format it.

Comment: You might use a script as Oracle does to style raw code - as seen in [BorderDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/BorderDemoProject/src/components/BorderDemo.java).  SO also styles code nicely, but uses a more complex server side solution to mark it up.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah in the project im currently working on we use Java and JavatoHtml to convert java to, well unsurprisingly, html.

Comment: Yes, JavatoHtml would be a good way to do it from the server-side.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new project called back2Code, which will decompile class files back to source code.

http://code.google.com/p/back2code/

1. Store the class files a location in server
2. Read the appropriate file.
3. Use the API to decompile it to the source code.
4. Display the source code , appropriately.

Comment: That's good solution only if one doesn't have source code (.java files). While compiling to byte code, compiler change some stuff, like local variables' names, etc, for optimization's sake. This reduce readability of decompiled java code.

Comment: Also Comments are fully ignored while decompiling

Answer (score -2):

For each java class generate a static html page and on click simple open that page.

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea, especially if there are more than just a few java files.  He should get it to create it dynamically using php and reading the contents of the file as if it were a plain text file, which essentially a .java file is.

Comment: Why generate an HTML for each class? all he needs is one HTML page.

Comment: With many html pages you can get syntax highlighting without javascript.